# C# windows Forms Data Grid View Height Resizing

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing this project here. I'm stuck with the Data Grid View I'm retrieving data from the database that the user enters I have RichTextBoxes as well as TextBoxes I want some data to be written in the form of a address for example in few lines

O'Connell Street,

Dublin,

Co.Dublin,

Ireland

Instead of having it in one line O'Connell Street,O'Connell Street,Co.Dublin, Ireland.

But all I can do with the grid view is stretch the length of the column out when i stretch the height the text doesn't drop down.

How do I manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you are trying to display this into a DataGridView, but to try and answer your question I'll try to explain how to add a "multiline" TextBox inside a DataGridView cell.

You must set the `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` property of the column to `DataGridViewTriState.True` and the `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`.

Here is an example if your DataGridView has only one column and that single row.

```
dgvAdress.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dgvAdress.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells);
dgvAdress.Rows.Add("O'Connell Street," + Environment.NewLine + "Dublin," + Environment.NewLine + "Co.Dublin," + Environment.NewLine + "Ireland");
```

You can of course dynamically fill the DataGridView, but I'd need some more information about your current data source.